# Postgresql tuning to be used as DatawareHouse

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, data-warehouse

I am assembling a Business Intelligence solution using the Pentaho software as a BI engine. Within this solution, I had to set up a requirements for a PostgreSQL database server.

The current situation is very easy, since no ETL process is being carried out for data extraction, so the PostgreSQL configuration has not changed it much, and it is practically as it is configured as "factory".
I would like to know what Postgres configuration parameters have to be touched and modified to optimize it as a Datawarehouse. I have seen a lot of documentation, but it is not clear to me at all, since one documentation says that such values have to be modified, and other documentation, other completely different values.

I would like to know just that, if there is a clearer and more precise documentation to optimize a postgres 9.6 to be used as a Pentaho DW.

Thank you very much

Comment: If performance is important for you, you should seriously consider using Postgres 12 instead of 9.6

Comment: It depends a lot on your queries and their frequency, on the size of the database, on the amount of RAM and the storage used.

Comment: 596/5000
Thank you very much for the answers,

In principle, since everything is in the initial phase, and there is no ELT mounted, there is no load or data transformation, I have practically left the configuration that Postgres defaults.I understand that as you use and add data, and consult and transform, you will have to change values in the Postgres configuration.

Initially I have given the postgres server about 8 GB of RAM, and I have changed a series of values based on that RAM, max_connections, shared_buffers, effective_cache_size, work mem, maintenance_work_mem ...